# Automatisation permalinks for each making of new page

Tags: permalinks, wp-redirect

I'm making a plugin. When I add a new page with a shortcode in my plugin and I redirect to this page, the url correctly appears but I get a 404 error page.

Each time to manually debug this problem, I have to go to the wordpress backend and go to *Settings > Permalinks* and click on the button to save options again ( even if I did not any changement ) and it works.

I don't why there is this problem.

Someone could explain me please ?
How can I automate this and avoid this problem ?

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` properly set up? I'd go through https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks to verify.

Comment: show us the code that creates the new page